# How to get jquery sprite zoom to work

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have an image and I am trying to use spritezoom on it. I am having a problem with it. Here is my code.

In my view

```
 <div class="col-xs-4 item-photo">
            @*<a href="~/Images/IMG_6878_resize-1200x1200.jpg"></a>*@
            <img class="zoom_01" style="max-width: 100%" src="~/Images/IMG_6878_resize-1200x1200.jpg" data-zoom-image="~/Images/IMG_6878_resize-1200x1200.jpg/"/>
        </div>
```

In my js sheet

```
$(".zoom_01").spritezoom({

});
```

Scipts I included:

```
@section scripts{ 
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Plugins/Easy-Flexible-jQuery-Image-Zoom-Plugin-Sprite-Zoom/src/jquery.spritezoom.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/ProductJs.js"></script>
}
```

Is there anything else I have to put into the juery function?

Comment: Have you included the script file for spritezoom`<script src="src/jquery.spritezoom.js"></script>` ??

Comment: Yes I have included it

Comment: any errors in console?

Comment: I get an error in the console which says http://localhost:51210/Product/undefined

Comment: Sorry, I noticed that i did not have  <script src="src/jquery.spritezoom.js"></script> so I put it in , but it underlines it in blue and then in the console it says Object doesn't support property or method 'spritezoom'

Comment: have you downloaded and included that script in project?